# Any idea for data structure that can used like redblack tree and hashtable at the same time?

Tags: data-structures, red-black-tree

i need a data structure that can find the minimum value in O(1) time at a given time and can easily be updated like a hash table.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially impossible. If a data structure supported constant-time insertion, deletion, and find-min, we could [sort a list in linear time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Performance_limits_and_advantages_of_different_sorting_techniques) by adding all elements of the list to such a data structure and repeatedly finding and removing the minimum element. We would need more powerful tools than comparisons and hashes to pull that off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a red-black tree itself, if you are willing to relax on the O(1) time constraint for inserts and deletes. The minimum lookup can still be O(1), if you cache it, and update it on every insert/delete.

So the data structure complexity will look like:

```
Insert: O(log n) time.
Delete: O(log n) time.
Minimum: O(1) time
```

Even if you could not modify the red-black tree implementation, but had one that provided:

```
Insert: O(log n) time.
Delete: O(log n) time.
Minimum: O(log n) time
```

(note: Minimium is O(log n)), then you can wrap that datastructure (composition!) and cache the minimum.

Something like:

```
class MinWrapper {
    private RBTree tree;
    private Value min;
    public Insert(x) {
        tree.Insert(x);
        min = tree.Minimum();
    }
    // etc
}
```